# Errror when uninstalling Docker

Tags: 14.04, docker

I´m trying to remove docker using this command

```
$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove docker
```

but unfortunatly I have always this error

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Can't mmap an empty file
E: Failed to truncate file - ftruncate (9: Bad file descriptor)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

when i run this command `$df -Th` here is what i found

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
ud             d tmp    3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /d
tmp            tmp       799M  592K  798M   1% /run
none           tmp       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmp       3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /run/shm
none           tmp       100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/d/s           ext4      3.9G  3.9G     0 100% /var
/d/s           ext4       30G  240M   28G   1% /opt
```

How could I solve this problem and uninstall my docker?
Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem this is not related to docker but related to less space in your system. your system have less space so that are not allowing you to run this command. check your system space using command:

```
df -Th
```

and if any partition near to full then try to create space by deleting or moving some file and also try

```
 sudo apt-get clean 
 sudo apt-get autoremove
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

**EDIT:**
your `/var` space is 100% so try to delete some space from it. you can delete logs file if not usable or delete other that is not important. once you create some space then you will be able to install or remove package and other activity.

Comment: @Bessa if this answer helped you then you can accept this answer by clicking on tick mark on left side of this answer that will be helpful for other who face similar problem and put comment if you any problem.

Comment: Yeah, I know that i don't have space that's why i want to remove docker , because i don't need it .....but i'm suprised why i have this error although  i want  only to remove but not to update or to install

Comment: this is not matter you are installing or deleting  because every action installation and deleting both perform I/O operation and it check  in `/var/lib/dpkg` . it need to use `/var/lib/dpkg/status` , `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` etc. but not able to parse this request due to insufficient space. `E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened`

Comment: first delete some file from system and make some space in system then you will be able to uninstall it.

Comment: I was following your instruction but at the end when i run the command
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
I have the same error :(

Comment: first delete some from `/var` directory. if your logs is not important then you can delete some logs from `/var/log/`

Comment: how to know which are important or not in the /var directory as well as in the /var/log/ so i could delete them ?

Comment: /var/log have logs only if you delete any it will not harm first try to delete syslog kern dmesg etc. why you have only 4 GB to /var . it should be grater .

Comment: i have deleted almost all the compressed files but when i run this command  `$ df- Th` i found that
    Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /d/s           ext4      3.9G  3.9G     0 100% /var

Comment: are working on physical machine or vm ?. better to increase size of `/var` if you any how delete some file and solve this issue for now then it will create again problem after some days you have to assign more space to /var. if you are working on vm then youcan easily add extra partition .

Comment: I`m working on VM

Comment: Okey thank you for your answer that help me to know where it is the probem :)
Should I click to question answered ?